Is writing black box tests as part of a bug report practiced anywhere?
Authors of BB tests* concern themselves with behavior instead of with means of achieving it. Customer support too. Why have I never seen a say L2** support operative file a bug with a "failing_test.py"? Why not create such positions?
This would prevent the following scenarios:

bug not reproducible(because of HW, SF or miscommunication)
bug not actually what was fixed
bug fixed last WEEK but a feature merge reintroduced it.

* - the domain of this question are web applications - that is a product where a BB test is simply documenting how would one navigate a website to achieve some result. For that there exist tools simpler than python even. Let's leave nuclear submarine targeting computers out of this.
** - traditionally L1 is phone operator, L2 is coder and L3 is architect. I'm talking about something like 1.5. Similarly to how a team lead is 2.5.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The simple answer is: QA and software testing is not a technical support or customer support role!
Most of the time, these roles don't have knowledge of testing fundamentals or techniques. They don't know how to write a test case or even a detailed bug report. They don't have any access to the code base, so even knowing about a "failing_test.py" file is unknown to them.
If the idea is for the tech/customer support to write a "failing_test.py" file, well, they don't have coding knowledge.
Any tech/customer support would need to learn the technical aspects of testing/coding for this to be beneficial. Most of the time, companies don't have time to teach this nor any incentive to teach it. If those roles learned this, they'd need to be paid a higher income, which companies don't like doing (it's unfortunate, but true in a lot of cases).
There's also a quota issue. A lot of companies have a quota on how many calls, chats, emails, etc, a tech/customer support employee must reach! Taking the time to do testing, writing a test case, or a coded test case takes time they don't have!
Then there's a question: do tech/customer support employees even want to learn this? Most don't! Those who do can be encouraged and mentored to learn, but those people are the exception. People who are in these roles are typically low-paid, under-educated, and don't have incentive/permission/authority to go beyond the scope of their role. They just report issues presented to them and move on.

Thanks, upvoted, I have heavily edited the question. The SE bot is correct that it's too open ended but You have shown it's answerable!
